# Prevent Ragel from calling actions multiple times while matching the same string

Tags: ruby, ragel

I have this parser:

```
class Parser
  %%{
    machine test_lexer;

    action s { s = p; puts "s#{p}" }
    action e { e = p; puts "e#{p}" }
    action captured {
      puts "captured #{s} #{e}"
    }
    key_value = "a" %s ("b" | "x" "c")+ %e %captured;
    tags = ("x"+)? key_value;

    main := tags*;
  }%%

  def initialize(data)
    data = data
    eof = data.length
    %% write data;
    %% write init;
    %% write exec;
  end
end


Parser.new(ARGV.first)
```

And I hit it with abxc then why does it call the captured twice / the e twice, and how can I prevent this ?

```
ragel -R simple.rl && ruby simple.rb "abxc"
s1
e2
captured 1 2
e4
captured 1 4
```

on github: https://github.com/grosser/ragel_example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the diagram for your machine, BTW: http://bit.do/stackoverflow-19621544 (created with [Erdos](http://sandbox.kidstrythisathome.com/erdos/)).

With "abxc" the `("b" | "x" "c")+` machine first matches the "b" and then the "xc". When transitioning from "b" (to "x") it calls the leaving actions (`e` and `captured`) for the first time, and when transitioning from "xc" (to EOF) it calls the leaving actions (`e` and `captured`) for the second time.

I guess the `e` action is supposed to set the end pointer in order to capture the string between start `s` and end `e`. If so, then Ragel calling the `e` action multiple times isn't really a problem, you just advance the end pointer like you already do.

Comment: Hmm ok, so if I add some silly end-of-expression character it works:

Comment: key_value = "a" %s ("b" | "x" "c")+ %e "z" %captured;